# How to find vertices of a rectangular prism given direction and elevation?

Tags: 3d, gml

So I am using a pretty much unknown language to program my game: GML.  If anyone knows the answer to my question, please keep it in as much math as possible to keep translation easy.
The variables are defined as follows:

drc = rotation counterclockwise from x to y

elev = rotation counterclockwise from x to z

The z axis is vertical in this situation.

If you prefer to have values for length, width, and height, here they are: 6 x 2 x 2.
Length is on the x axis, width on y, and height on z.

Comment: Just create your prism in axis-aligned orientation and then apply rotation transformations on its vertices.

Comment: Thanks, I did and it worked.  I was just over-thinking things.